# GemBox - scroll into view functionality missing?

Tags: .net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm working with GemBox (version 3.5) for the first time and have one problem. When opening a generated XLSX file, it is always scrolled to the bottom of the worksheet. I (or, rather, my customer) want it to start out at the top left position.

Is there any way to programmatically set the top visible cell before saving, i.e a "scroll into view" or "scroll to top" function? I haven't found anything in the GemBox documentation or on the interwebs that addresses this issue.

Comment: Isn't that an excel feature? The last active cell is saved. If you can set cell A1 in worksheet 1 as active and save the workbook should open on that cell.

Comment: There is no "set active" functionality AFAICS, but I tried setting the value of the top left cell as the last thing before saving. Still scrolled to the bottom when opening, though...

Comment: Hmmm, it was worth a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging I found another way of doing it with [ViewOptions](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/T_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelViewOptions.htm) on Worksheet ('ws' in this example):

```
ws.ViewOptions.FirstVisibleColumn = 0;
ws.ViewOptions.FirstVisibleRow = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

To set an active cell with GemBox.Spreadsheet 3.5 you can use [ExcelViewOptions.SelectedCells](http://archive.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/Help35/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelViewOptions_SelectedCells.htm) .

```
// Create new excel file.
ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile();
// Create new excel sheet.
ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Sample");

// Add some sample content.
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 5000))
    ws.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "Sample";

// Set SelectedCells to "A1" cell.
ws.ViewOptions.SelectedCells = ws.Cells.GetSubrange("A1", "A1");

// Save as XLSX file.
ef.SaveXlsx("Sample.xlsx");
```

**EDIT 2017-07-17:**
In newer version, GemBox.Spreadsheet 4.1, you can specify one or more cell ranges to be selected with [ExcelWorksheet.SelectedRanges](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelWorksheet_SelectedRanges.htm), like the following:

```
// Set "A1" as selected range.
ws.SelectedRanges.Add(ws.Cells.GetSubrange("A1"));

ef.Save("Sample.xlsx");
```

Comment: Nice. I've found another option as well, see below